# how to store the FIX message into the database

Tags: c#, database, quickfix

I want to know that how to store the FIX message into the database to keep the log of the transferring message. Is it to store whole message into the single column of the table or store the whole message in the Tag value format i.e. column names should be tag names or tag values and actual transferring message values in the row. can anyone give me suggestion on it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a built-in feature of QuickFIX.  Even when you configure QuickFIX to use a DB for the message store, it is not meant for application-level access.  That is, it is not intended that you are to be able to access or manipulate it, and QF does not give you methods to do so.

That said, implementing DB storage at the application level is not very difficult, and the questions you're asking are dependent on your needs and preferences.  There isn't really a general correct answer.

One tip, though, is to not do the DB-save in the QuickFIX callbacks themselves.  You should probably do that work *off* of the QF thread.  Instead, I think those callbacks to save those messages into a separate queue, and a different thread should be responsible for operating on that queue and saving those messages into the DB.

Comment: According to your suggestion another thead resposible for saving messages into DB but can you please gide me on how to store message in the DB using tags as the columns of the table or whole message in a single column in sql server 2005. How each option affects in terms of load to DB or at serverside DB? can anyone give me suggestion on it. Thanks in advance

Comment: No, I can't.  That is a very broad question, and the answers directly depend on your business cases.

Comment: but can you guide me about it.i really need it at my work.if you could help me in any way.it will be very helpful for me.